# Are there limits on number of Google Analytics 4 dimension values?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am trying to work out whether there are any limits on the number of unique `event_params.value.string_value`'s for a particular `event_params.key` in GA4? In this case I have a custom event called `dispatch` with a custom `event_params.key` called `action`. `event_params.value.string_value` has values like `BUILDING_USE`, `MOVE_MOBILE_UNIT` etc. I am seeking to find out whether there are any limits as to how many different values this can take? Can we send through an unlimited variety of different string_values here or is there a limit on this?

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like in BigQuery:

[image: Google Analytics BigQuery screenshot]

This is how it looks in Google Analytics itself:

[image]